# Is there a way to make Python open up Notepad (through subprocess) and type in the current date and time on its own?

Tags: python-2.7, date

I've made the following code to open up Notepad through subprocess and it works as intended.

`osCommandString = 'notepad'
 process = subProcess.Popen(osCommandString)`

Is it possible to make Python type in the recently opened file the current date and time?

Comment: It would be much, much easier to directly write to a file using Python then open the file in whatever text editor you want https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: It is possible, but it involves discovering the Notepad window and sending it keystroke messages. But your program would have no easy way of discovering how the user interacts with Notepad. So, for example, the user does some typing and saves the file. Your program will have trouble finding out the filename. Or the user closes Notepad without saving. Your program won't know that either. As an alternative consider incorporating a bare-bones text editor into your program. If you use Tk then there is a simple example here: https://www.instructables.com/id/Create-a-Simple-Python-Text-Editor/ .